# getText() returning blank

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

```html
<div class="header"> Account</div>
<div class="header"> Email</div>
<div class="value ng-binding">$50</div>==$0
```

Above is the HTML snippet, i am trying to fetch text: $50, with getText().To locate the element i have used className and xpath.

The problem that i am facing is that, Selenium is able to locate the element but return blank,in place of $50.

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".value.ng-binding")).getText(); this returns blank. Here i am using cssSelector to locate the element, and have tried with className and Xpath also.

Comment: Share the site. If possible.

Comment: I would not be able to as i am working on restricted company network.

Comment: @HimanshuVarshney `findElements()` returns multiple elements, did you mean `findElement()` (with singular **Element**)?

Comment: Yes, it is findElement()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead try using `.getAttribute("innerHTML");` on the ClassName to return $50.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, being new to selenium and not sure What  innerHTML is ?

Comment: element.getText() returns all visible text in all children of the element. element.getAttribute("innerHTML") returns all html inside of the element you're looking for (so including html elements if they exist). They should both however work for this element. There is no reason getText() should not work here.

Comment: Thanks jude, it worked for me,however getText() is giving blank.

Comment: Himanshu, not sure why it isn't working. Use the Sources tab in Chrome Developer Tools and use the Watch section to create your lines of code and validate them at the same time, that's what I do.

Answer (score 2):

it is a good practice if u use 'id' to fetch data in javascript. For your problem you can try like the code below:

```
<div class="header"> Account</div>
<div class="header"> Email</div>
<div id="value" class="ng-binding">$50</div>==$0
```

and then try

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#value.ng-binding")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following approach :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".value.ng-binding")));
String text = el.getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

Output: $50

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

agree with Saurabh Gaur

C#

IWebElement div = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".value.ng-binding"));

Console.WriteLine(div.Text);